# How do I find if a string is in a list in a specific column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 large dataframes I want to compare against each other.
I have `.split(" ")` one of the columns and placed the result in a new column of the dataframe.
I now want to check and see if a value exists in that new column, instead of using a `.contains()` in the original column, to avoid the value getting picked up within a word.

Here is what I've tried and why I'm frustrated.

```
row['company'][i] == 'nom'

L_df['Name split'][7126853] == "['nom', '[this', 'is', 'nom]']"

row['company'][i] in L_df['Name split'][7126853] == True   (this is the index where I know the specific value occurs)

row['company'][i] in L_df['Name split'] #WHAAT? == False (my attempt to check the entire column); why is this false when I've shown it exists?

L_df[L_df['Name split'].isin([row['company'][i]])] == [empty]
```

edit: I should additionally add that I am trying to set up a process where I can iterate to check entries in the smaller dataset against the larger one.

```
result = L_df[ #The [9] is a placeholder for our iterable 'i' that will go row by row
    L_df['Company name'].str.contains(row['company'][i], na=False) #Can be difficult with names like 'Nom'
    #(row['company'][i] in L_df['Name split'])
    & L_df['Industry'].str.contains('marketing', na=False) #Unreliable currently, need to get looser matches; min. reduction
    & L_df['Locality'].str.contains(row['city'][i], na=False)  #Reliable, but not always great at reducing results
    & ((row['workers'][i] >= L_df['Emp Lower bound']) & (row['workers'][i] <= L_df['Emp Upper bound'])) #Unreliable
]
```

the first line is what I am trying to replace with this new process, so I don't get matches when 'nom' appears in the middle of words.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that first merges the two dataframes into one and then uses lambda to process the columns of interest.  The result is placed in a new column `found`:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data={'company': ['findme', 'asdf']})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data={'Name split': ["here is a string including findme and then some".split(" "), "something here".split(" ")]})
combined_df = pandas.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
combined_df['found'] = combined_df.apply(lambda row: row['company'] in row['Name split'], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
  company                                         Name split  found
0  findme  [here, is, a, string, including, findme, and, ...   True
1    asdf                                  [something, here]  False
```

**EDIT:**
In order to compare each value from the `company` column to *every* cell in the `Name split` column in  the other dataframe, and to have access to the whole row from the latter dataframe, I would simply loop through each column, see here:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'company': ['findme', 'asdf']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name split': ["random text".split(" "), "here is a string including findme and then some".split(" "), "somethingasdfq here".split(" ")], '`another column`': [3, 1, 2]})
for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row1['company'] in row2['Name split']:
            # do something here with row2
            print(row2)
```

Probably not very efficient, but could be improved by breaking out of the inner loop as soon as a match is found *if we only need one match*.

Comment: I am attempting to adapt this to my situation as your code uses a single dataframe, where I have 2 that I am comparing against each other. I end up with ```L_df[L_df.apply(lambda row: I_df['company'][i] in row['Name split'], axis=1)]``` but unforunately this also captures anything within the word itself.  My example uses 'nom' and it is picked up in several words similar to how ```.contains()``` works. ex: ['nomisoft', 'ltd'] was flagged as True instead of just the desired ['nom', '[this', 'is', 'nom]']

Comment: I've added a concatenation of two dataframes to the solution.  Would that work in your case?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. I appreciate it.
Unfortunately this is still not working. I have attempted to adapt it to my uses through ```df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'company': 'nom'})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=L_df['Name split'])
combined_df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
combined_df['found'] = combined_df.apply(lambda row: 'nom' in row['Name split'], axis=1)
combined_df``` encounters an error of "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index". I believe is occurring because they are different sizes? using ```row['company'] ``` instead of 'nom' has the same error

Comment: I think that error comes from the first statement; `df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'company': 'nom'})` which needs to include brackets around `'nom'`. Try `df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'company': ['nom']})`.

Comment: I don't understand why your version only checks entire words vs the ```L_df[L_df.apply(lambda row: I_df['company'][i] in row['Name split'], axis=1)] ``` version that will pick up the characters within a word?

Comment: It's hard for me to figure out since I don't have these dataframes set up. But I'm starting to think I may have misunderstood. Do you want to search for each value in the 'company' column across the entire 'Name split' column?  So if 'nom' is at index 7126853, the new column should return 'True' even though it was found at index, say, 1000?  Or should it only be 'True' if found at index 7126853 in 'Name split'?

Comment: I want to search the entire column of 'Name split' in one dataframe (L_df) for entries in a 'company' column of another dataframe (I_df). When a match is found, I want to see the entire row from L_df. I am combining this condition with others in the form of ```L_df[L_df['something'].str.contains(I_df['stuff']) & ....& .... & .... etc...]```

Comment: Ok I see.  I have added another option to the solution, hope this helps!

Comment: ```df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'company': [I_df['company'][i]] } )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name split': [L_df['Name split']] } )
for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row1['company'] in row2['Name split']:
            # do something here with row2
            print(row2)``` gives no results. When I remove  the "[]" around ```[L_df['Name split']]```, i get the inner-word false positives, catching the 'nom' within a word. Marking things like 'economics' as True.